# Pytorch low gpu util after first epoch

Tags: pytorch, gpu, dataloader

Hi I'm training my pytorch model on remote server.
All the job is managed by slurm.

My problem is 'training is extremely slower after training first epoch.'

I checked gpu utilization.
On my first epoch, utilization was like below image.
[image]

I can see gpu was utilized.
But from second epoch utilized percentage is almos zero
[image]

My dataloader code like this

```py
class img2selfie_dataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, path, transform, csv_file, cap_vec):
        self.path = path
        self.transformer = transform
        self.images = [path + item for item in list(csv_file['file_name'])]
        self.smiles_list = cap_vec
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img = Image.open(self.images[idx])
        img = self.transformer(img)
        label = self.smiles_list[idx]
        label = torch.Tensor(label)
        return img, label.type(torch.LongTensor)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.images)
```

My dataloader is defined like this

```py
train_data_set = img2selfie_dataset(train_path, preprocess, train_dataset, train_cap_vec)
train_loader = DataLoader(train_data_set, batch_size = 256, num_workers = 2, pin_memory = True)
val_data_set = img2selfie_dataset(train_path, preprocess, val_dataset, val_cap_vec)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_data_set, batch_size = 256, num_workers = 2, pin_memory = True)
```

My training step defined like this

```py
train_loss = []
valid_loss = []
epochs = 20
best_loss = 1e5
for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
    print('Epoch {}/{}'.format(epoch, epochs))
    print('-' * 10)
    epoch_train_loss, epoch_valid_loss = train(encoder_model, transformer_decoder, train_loader, val_loader, criterion, optimizer)
    train_loss.append(epoch_train_loss)
    valid_loss.append(epoch_valid_loss)
    if len(valid_loss) > 1:
        if valid_loss[-1] < best_loss:
            print(f"valid loss on this {epoch} is better than previous one, saving model.....")
            torch.save(encoder_model.state_dict(), 'model/encoder_model.pickle')
            torch.save(transformer_decoder.state_dict(), 'model/decoder_model.pickle')
            best_loss = valid_loss[-1]
            print(best_loss)
    print(f'Epoch : [{epoch}] Train Loss : [{train_loss[-1]:.5f}], Valid Loss : [{valid_loss[-1]:.5f}]')
```

In my opinion, if this problem comes from my code. It wouldn't have hitted 100% utilization in first epoch.

Comment: It is slower after the first epoch (forward + backward pass) or when it prints the training loss (last line in training loop)? where is your backprop?

Comment: I do backprop in train function, after it print loss, it's getting slower

Comment: When you print the loss, it is not the end of the first epoch. The optimiser calculates the gradients for the optimiser, which might take long time depending of the size of the dataset. After you backpropagate the weights, I suggest you to print ("end of epoch number: ", epoch). 
What is the y-axis in the  plot?

Comment: is that the used GPU memory or the power consumption?

Comment: @PrakharSharma Oh, I should've mentioned about it, it's gpu utilization percentage.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue with moving my training data into local drive.

My remote server(school server) policy was storing personel data into NAS.
And file i/o from NAS proveked heavy load on network.
It was also affected by other user's file i/o from NAS.

After I moved training data into NAS, everything is fine.